# Authorization bearer token Angular 5

Tags: angular, header, authorization, bearer-token

I am confused about how to create a good header for a simple Get request in Angular 5.

This is what I need to do in Angular: 
[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
  getUserList(): Observable<UserList[]> {
    const headers = new Headers();
    let tokenParse = JSON.parse(this.token)             
    headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${tokenParse}`);
    const opts = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });  
    console.log(JSON.stringify(opts));
    const users = this.http.get<UserList[]>(this.mainUrl, opts)
    return users
            .catch(this.handleError.handleError);         
  }
```

This is the response in my console.log:

```
{"method":null,"headers":{"Authorization":["Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImYwODZlM2FiYTk0ZjVhMjVmNDhiNzlkYmI2YWUwOWY4YzE2MTUyMzg2N2I5MDZiY2MzNWQyNWJiYTZmYTE4YjEwZjA1MjZiNThkZjE2Y2FjIn0.eyJhdWQiOiJmMDExY2M1OC00MGNlLTQzYTktOGY3MS04NDI0OTRlM2E5OTciLCJqdGkiOiJmMDg2ZTNhYmE5NGY1YTI1ZjQ4Yjc5ZGJiNmFlMDlmOGMxNjE1MjM4NjdiOTA2YmNjMzVkMjViYmE2ZmExOGIxMGYwNTI2YjU4ZGYxNmNhYyIsImlhdCI6MTUyMzU1MTQ0NSwibmJmIjoxNTIzNTUxNDQ1LCJleHAiOjE1MjM1NTQ0NDUsInN1YiI6IjIiLCJzY29wZXMiOlsiYXV0aGVudGljYXRlZCIsImFuZ3VkcnUiXX0.E-WdQTl7nPDW0gj0rohfql-QgnAinzvDxPR-pySMrG07XFY9tA6Ex7IL23pDBmKDmQO8RcZKa0L5r6SRQq9_iqzMWzn5Zxp94J9TJrpZ2KGMoLR_FbK_tpC5G5q5vUnCe3q34sH7cPdT_2cI704OWWaYmIUKKpXWUIG0PJw_uKSJ_uOifPv59RZGQkoaQ9gPywDKe-uamm1Faug-Kk2YnFMoEJq7ou19zyxgdpX80ZTPUae67uB0PGLRuvxfGaqVsJ8k0NunAY3-pyUnBwR_3eeuOxf4TyfW2aiOJ9kuPgsfV4Z1JD7nMpNtTHMJaXEyNkBW8RlYHD1pj4dkdnsDmw"]},"body":null,"url":null,"withCredentials":null,"responseType":null}
```

It looks pretty. But gives me this error

> GET http://druang.dd:8080/user-list?_format=json 403 (Forbidden)

There is another clue to solve this mystery. In Sublime text, If I put the mouse over `opts` it says something like:

> ERROR in src/app/services/userlist.service.ts(33,59): error TS2345:
>   Argument of type 'RequestOptions' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[];
>   }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.   Types of property 'headers'
>   are incompatible.
>       Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>         Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>           Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.

Any idea??
Here is the full [Git repo](https://github.com/josuevalrob/angudru)
THanks for your help!

Comment: I think you are importing the wrong class for Headers try to check angular documentation in version 5 the http service was deprecated for httpClient service but the httpClient is in @angular/common and the other one is in @angular/http you cannot mix classes from those ones cause it will cause errors. To me your errors looks like you are using http from "@angular/common" and Headers from "@angular/http" instead the HttpHeaders from "@angular/common"

Comment: Hi, thanks @Nicu this are my import: `import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';` according to the angular [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders)

Comment: Great :D @angular/http it will be replaced with @angular/common/http removed in ng 6 I suppose.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I suggest to use `HttpInterceptor` for setting default HTTP headers on outgoing requests rather than adding an additional HTTP header to each call.

[HTTP Client - Setting default headers @ angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/http#setting-default-headers)

---

In your example you can do the following:

```ts
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';

getLoggedInUser(auth_token): Observable<any> {
  const headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth_token}`
  })
  return this.http.get(apiUrl, { headers: headers })
}
```

Comment: Just to add, the token should be prepended by 'Bearer ', so in your example, it would be 'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth_token}`

Comment: I needed to use HttpHeaders rather than Headers, but after that it all worked. 

Comment: just out of curiosity, is the use of ` symbol to combine text?

Answer (score 23):

For `get` requests, I used the following code and it works

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

getServerList(){
    var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mpManagerToken'))
     });
    return this.http.get<Server[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/Servers/GetServerList`, { headers: reqHeader });
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In Angular 6 and 7, this method can be used to intercept all HTTP request and add the bearer token.

Implementation tutorial is available here. [Youtube](https://youtu.be/MGCC2zTb0t4), this channel has all the tutorials.

Interceptor component

```
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpUserEvent,
  HttpEvent
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from '../shared/user.service';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.headers.get('No-Auth') === 'True') {
      return next.handle(req.clone());
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem('userToken') != null) {
      const clonedreq = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set(
          'Authorization',
          'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('userToken')
        )
      });
      return next.handle(clonedreq).pipe(
        tap(
          succ => {},
          err => {
            if (err.status === 401) {
              // this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
            } else if ((err.status = 403)) {
              // this.router.navigateByUrl('/forbidden');
              // alert(err.localStorage.getItem('userToken'));
            }
          }
        )
      );
    } else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    }
  }
}
```

Guard component

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  Router
} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from '../shared/user.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) {}
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean {
    if (localStorage.getItem('userToken') != null) {
      const roles = next.data['roles'] as Array<string>;
      if (roles) {
        const match = this.userService.roleMatch(roles);
        if (match) {
          return true;
        } else {
          // tslint:disable-next-line: quotemark
          this.toastr.info("You don't have access to this page");
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          // this.router.navigate(['/forbidden']);
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Add it to app.modules.ts

```
providers: [
    ConfirmationDialogService,
    UserService,
    DoctorService,
    { provide: OwlDateTimeIntl, useClass: DefaultIntl },
    { provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS, useValue: MY_MOMENT_FORMATS },
    AuthGuard,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
```

Then the guard is added to route

```
 {
    path: 'adminPanel',
    component: AdminPanelComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: { roles: ['Admin'] }
  },
```

Answer (score 8):

Two things:

1. `headers.append(...)` does not mutate the headers object, so your authorization header is not being sent. You need to do `headers = headers.append(...)`
2. Try `this.http.get<UserList[]>(this.mainUrl, { headers: headers });`

Comment: 1) `headers = headers.append`gives me: Cannot assign Headers because it is a constant or a read-only property

Comment: either change the declaration from `const headers` to  let headers` or do `const headers = new Headers().append('Authorization', `Bearer ${tokenParse}`);

Comment: With `let` it said: `Type void is not assignable to type 'Headers'`

Comment: And the other option, works, but when I Set   `const opts = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });` I got : `ERROR in src/app/services/userlist.service.ts(33,37): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Headers'.`

Comment: Also, if i forgot about the options, and go straight to the `{headers:headers}` in the http get request, I got this: `ERROR in src/app/services/userlist.service.ts(35,59): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.`

Comment: I found the solution... If you can explain me, thanks!. `const users = this.http.get<UserList[]>(this.mainUrl, { headers:new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${tokenParse}`)})`

Answer (score 3):

I have used all the above suggested formats to append the headers with access token, its adding null like "Authorization Bearer null" in the Request header.
If I print the accesstoken just before the line of adding/cloning headers, the accesstoken value is being printed in the browser console. Here's the format I am using.

```
console.log("Inside Interceptor accesstoken : " + this.oauthService.getAccessToken());
    req = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
         Authorization: 'Bearer ' +  this.oauthService.getAccessToken()
      }
    });
    return next.handle(req);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not very good at programming,but with a little of try and failure
if found this:

```
  getUserList(): Observable<UserList[]> {
    let tokenParse = JSON.parse(this.token)    
    // let myHeaders = new Headers();
    // myHeaders.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${tokenParse}`);
    // let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: myHeaders});
    const users = this.http.get<UserList[]>(this.mainUrl, { headers:new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', `Bearer ${tokenParse}`)})
    // const users = this.http.get<UserList[]>(this.mainUrl, options);
    return users
            .catch(this.handleError.handleError);         
  }
```

It doesn't really matter if I use `.set` or `.append`, at the end of the day, it works in both cases...

I don't really know what is happening, so, if someone wants to explain it in the comments, you are welcome...

Answer (score 2):

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
```

that worked

Answer (score 2):

While @HassanRahman shows it for `get` requests, for `post` requests,

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

getServerList(){

    postData = { your data }
    var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mpManagerToken'))
     });
    return this.http.post<Server[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/Servers/GetServerList`, postData, { headers: reqHeader });
}
```

Comment: In my opinion very important answer, I don't know why downvoted. In my case I had post method on server without parameters, so had `this.router.post<string>('https://localhost:5001/api/method', 
null, 
{headers: { 'Authorization': \`Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('authToken')}\`, }})
.subscribe(data => 
{ //now use data
window.location.href = data; });`
Of course it is better to use interceptor, but I think that it is also important to see simple basic example like this with both `post` and `get`.

Comment: @LazarĐorđević Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

ALTERNATIVE WAY
Set HttpHeader using set or append function

```
const reqHeader = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.accessToken);
```

`return this.http.get<any[]>(this.webApiUrlEndPoint, { headers: reqHeader});`