# Don't get token after login in Angular 6

Tags: angular, laravel

I would like get token after login.

This is my login.component

```
login() {
    this.service.login(this.user.value.email, this.user.value.password)
      .then(
        res => console.log(res),
        error => this.handleError(error.error.error)
      );
    // this.router.navigate(['/painel']);
}
```

And now I have my authentication.ts

```
    login(email: string, password: string) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post<any>(this.api, { email, password })
        .toPromise()
        .then((res) => {

          if(res) {
              this.isAuthenticated = true;
              this.showMenuEmitter.emit(true);
              localStorage.setItem("token", res.token);
              localStorage.setItem("user_id", res.user.id);  
              this.router.navigate(['/painel']);
              resolve(res.token);
             } else {
               this.isAuthenticated = false;
               this.showMenuEmitter.emit(false);
               reject(false);
             }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          reject(error);
        });
    })
    return promise;
  }
```

And now, I need take the token to work in provider.service

```
 api: string = `${environment.apiHost}/painel`;
  public headers = new HttpHeaders(
   {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
   }
  );

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  create(user: any, path: string) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.api}/${path}`, user, { headers: this.headers });
        // toPromise();
  }
```

But when I logged I get error in console like this:

> Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/panel/users: 401 Unauthorized

how to get token in another service after login ?

I can only get token if I take refresh in the page so I get token.

Comment: This answer might help you with your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49830673/6891406

Comment: I already ready something about interceptor but I dont know to implement its, I new to create a interceptorService.ts for exemple ?

Comment: yes you need to create an interceptor service example TokenInterceptorService and inject it on your AppComponent (provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptorService, multi: true) and after that whenever you have http calls, it will also pass on this interceptor.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did this way
I created a TokenInterceptorService.ts

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let tokenizedReq = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      }
    })
    return next.handle(tokenizedReq)
  }
}
```

and in my app.module I imported this module http interceptors

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and my interceptor service too

```
import { TokenInterceptorService } from './shared/services/token-interceptor/token-interceptor.service';
```

and finally in providers of app.module added
providers: [
    ... 
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptorService, multi: true }
  ],

and work perfect, now I can get token after logedd thanks @KShewengger for your help